# How to get User Photo Data from nested Object in SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql

So, I have `Tag_Case__c` Object. this object has relationship with `Case` Object
I wanna get `SmallPhotoUrl` data from `Case Owner`

I was tried use something like this following code, but it not works

```
SELECT ID, Case__r.Subject, Case__r.Owner.Name, Case__r.Owner.SmallPhotoUrl FROM Tag_Case__c
```

and Also

```
SELECT ID, Case__r.Subject, Case__r.Owner.Name, (SELECT Case__r.OwnerId FROM User__r) FROM Tag_Case__c
```

But still erro. Actually, I can get this field `Case__r.Owner.Name`. but error when I put this field on select condition `Case__r.Owner.SmallPhotoUrl`

Anyone can help me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! When you're getting an error message, you should include the full text of the error message (don't try to paraphrase it). It'll also help to know how your objects are related here. Do you have a `Case__c` relationship field on your `Tag_Case__c` SObject, or is it the other way around (your Case object has a `Tag_Case__c` relationship field)? Please [edit] your question to add those details.

Comment: I was done with this issue. I just combine the data from apex code. Thanks @DerekF

Answer (score 0):

Case Owner is a [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_name.htm)-pointing field, because a case can be owned by a User or a Queue (Group). As such, the Name object allows common fields to be exposed in SOQL, such as Name, Email, etc, but not some standard and any custom user fields.

You can use a formula field to expose the value: `Case__r.Owner:User.SmallPhotoUrl` (note, this means you need to create a custom field, SOQL alone won't get you there).

You can use [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) to get the data: `SELECT TYPEOF Case__r.Owner WHEN User THEN SmallPhotoUrl END FROM ...`.

Depending on what *exactly* you're doing, you might just choose to use two queries instead of one.

Comment: I was done with this issue. I combine the data from apex code. so, first I query on user, then I join user data with case data as Map object. Thanks @sfdcfox.